# MySQL Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' ubuntu 20.04 and MYSQL8

Tags: permissions, mysql

I keep getting this error. I have been looking at a few QA sites trying to reset my local mysql pw.
I have added the `skip grant tables` under `[mysqld]` and now I am running in safe mode. I have followed these steps

```
mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &
use mysql;
update user set password=PASSWORD(”my_password”) where user=’root’;
```

When I get to the last step on the update I get this error:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '("my_password") where user="root"' at line 1
```

I also tried

```
    UPDATE mysql.user SET 
    authentication_string=PASSWORD(''), 
    plugin='mysql_native_password'
   WHERE User='root' AND Host='localhost';
```

and this

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'root';
```

But get the same error:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Ihost IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'root'' at line 1
```

Not sure how to reset my password at this point.

Answer (score 1):

I am updating what works for me everytime, follow these steps

1. Login as root user

   `sudo mysql -u root`
2. select mysql db

   `use mysql;`
3. Check plugin used for desired user, if it is auth_login? change this to mysql_native_password, using this query

   `UPDATE user SET plugin='mysql_native_password' WHERE User='root';`
4. Now use this query to update root or any other user's password

   `ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'newpassword';`
5. Restart mysql service using

   `sudo systemctl restart mysql`